# i already have a Key in my component but why is it still looking for a unique key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am new to **react** **js** and i'm trying to pass a data from one component to another using ***Link to*** and this method is what i found on the net..

ERROR:
index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Videos`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:134999:31
at Videos (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:5570:81)
at div
at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:135601:29)
at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:135803:29)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:135232:30)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:134853:35)
at div
at App

Videos.js

function Videos() {

```
const [vids, setVids] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('videos').orderBy('videoDate', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        setVids(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            data: doc.data(),
            id: doc.id
        })))
    })
}, []);

return (
    <div className="Videos">
        <h2> Available Lessons </h2>
        <div className="Videos__uploads">

            {
                vids.map(({ id, data }) => (
                    <Link to={{ pathname: `/play/${id}`, data: data}}>
                        {console.log(id)}
                        <VideoCard
                            key={id}
                            videoTitle={data.videoTitle}
                            videoDate={data.videoDate}
                            videoCaption={data.videoCaption}
                            videoUrl={data.videoUrl}
                        />
                    </Link>
                ))

            }

        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Videos;

VideoPlayer.js
function VideoPlayer({ videoTitle }) {
return (

## Hello{videoTitle}

)
}
//im just trying to print out the videoTitle here.. but even the **Hello** is not rendering.

but my focus on this question is why is it still looking for a key when i already put a key on ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an unique key to `Link` not to `VideoCard`.

```js
vids.map(({ id, data }) => (
    <Link key={id} to={{ pathname: `/play/${id}`, data: data}}>
        {console.log(id)}
        <VideoCard
            videoTitle={data.videoTitle}
            videoDate={data.videoDate}
            videoCaption={data.videoCaption}
            videoUrl={data.videoUrl}
        />
    </Link>
))
```

Comment: ohhhh.. i'll try it.. thank you!